# Issue switching app to Dark Mode when device is in dark mode | Swift iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

When dark mode is already enabled on the device and I open my app all of the color sets that specify dark mode are not being applied:

**But when having the app already open and switching to Dark Mode from Control Center, the following code changes the color:**

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    guard let previousTraitCollection = previousTraitCollection else {return}
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if previousTraitCollection.hasDifferentColorAppearance(comparedTo: traitCollection) {
            //Dark Mode
            let inputBackground = UIColor(named: "TEST1backgroundColor")
            let inputPlaceholder = UIColor(named: "TEST1placeholderColor")

            passwordBack.layer.backgroundColor = inputBackground?.cgColor
            TextField1.placeholderColor = inputPlaceholder!
            TextField2.placeholderColor = inputPlaceholder!

            TextField1.textColor = inputPlaceholder!
            TextField2.textColor = inputPlaceholder!
    }
  }
}
```

How can have this color change be applied when starting an already in Dark Mode?

Answer (score 1):

`CGColors` don't react to dark or light mode. You don't show the declaration of `passwordBack`, but assuming it's a `UIView` or a subclass, set its `backgroundColor` property directly to `inputBackground` instead of using `layer.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 0):

just used appareance for named color in assets like this. [image]
so when the app open and the dark mode is on all collors would change to their correspondin dark appareance.

Comment: How do I apply these colors like `black_50` or `black7` to say `demoTestField.textColor = ?`

Comment: When doing `demoTextField.textColor = black_50` the syntax Is incorrect

Comment: You would say `demoTestField.textColor = UIColor(named: "black7")` or whatever.  Or you can do it in Interface Builder. You're not already doing that? No wonder you're having trouble with this. You need to watch at least _one_ of the WWDC 2019 videos on this topic, eh.

Comment: You shoul used as you do  demoTestField.textColor = UIColor(named: "black7") as Matt suggested that’s the way even for cgcolors so all appareances are applied

Comment: Ok understood, but this still does not solve the main issue I was having which is the app not applying dark mode when the app is launched and the phone is set to dark mode, how can this be done? Should I set the color for each think twice? Once in viewDidLoad and once traitCollectionDidChange?

Comment: Watch the video for wwdc man there is every thing explained you must provided app appareance for each color that is needed I dark mode and you should have it